# Setup development environment for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, office-dev-pnp, development-enviroment

I would like to create a development environment for SharePoint online based on agile on azure DevOps with sandbox for testing purposes and code review.

We migrated to the SharePoint online and I am new to the SharePoint Online development. What is the best approach for the SharePoint online? We used to side inject scripts and custom template and Wfc services.we also had a code repository to publish our code with approval process one azure DevOps pipeline.

I learned the I can inject scripts to SharePoint site classic. I am new to nodejs. Does it worth it to implement our solution on SharePoint online or we need to start developing standalone web applications for our tools?

Answer (score 0):

So, the devil is going to be in the details, and you haven't provided enough details.

Are you migrating existing applications over to SPO or starting from scratch? Are you looking to just get them over as-is or are you re-imagining them?

Are you heavily invested in farm solutions on the old platform? If so you're going to have to figure out how to re-implement them in Online.

Are you targeting classic or modern experience? (You should be going Modern unless you have a compelling reason not to.)  If classic, do you have plans to upgrade to modern at some point?

Once you can better articulate where you're going, you'll be better positioned to figure out how to get there.

As far as a sandbox, you can either use a dedicated tenant or set aside one or more site collections as test environment. Which to use will depend on the complexity of your solution, the complexity of any external integrations, and a few other things. For simpler projects, use dedicated site collections on the production tenant.

There's no reason you can't continue to use your existing source control and DevOps procedures - those really don't have any bearing on your target environment. You'll have to reconfigure them of course.

Good luck, hope this helps!